# Search/substition completion in Evil mode

Tags: evil

In Evil mode, in the Normal state, with the `evil-search-module` variable set to `Evil interactive search`, I would like to use some kind of auto-completion functionality like `Ctrl+n` or `Ctrl+p` so that I don't have to type the full string I am searching for. For example, if I wanted to turn the line

```
foo bar grue
```

into

```
foo bar zork
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

1. Type `:s/g`
2. Hit `Ctrl+n` (or some other concise key/combo).
3. See the command prompt change to `:s/grue`.
4. Type `/zork<RET>`.

The steps I've given above fail at step 2. At that point, instead of using the next match, Evil outputs the error message, "No later matching history item".

I have also tried using the suggestions given as answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19730567/82216), but these do not work either:

- Hitting `Ctrl+f` while in the middle of entering a substitution command simply causes Emacs to output the message "End of buffer".
- Using `q:is/g<Ctrl+n>` causes Emacs to output the error message "No dynamic expansion for `s/g' found".

What can I do to overcome or work around this?

*Update: see [Evil bug #166](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issues/166/some-key-bindings-are-missing-in-command#comment-20876335), which refers to this issue.*

Comment: I'm not sure how Evil's command mode works, but maybe try using `hippie-expand`. Many people bind it to `M-/`.

Comment: @nanny, Thanks for the suggestion. Hitting `M-/` while in the middle of typing a substitution command causes Emacs to output "Scanning for dabbrevs...done", but doesn't complete the search string. If I instead attempt to type `M-x hippie-expand<RET>` in the middle of typing a substitution, Emacs instead outputs, "Command attempted to use minibuffer while in minibuffer".

Comment: It's not bound to `M-/` by default (it's not bound to anything). It was a suggestion. Additionally, as you've found, you cannot use `M-x` while in the minibuffer, you must bind functions to keys if you want to use them.

Comment: @nanny, thanks again. I haven't tried to use hippie-expand before, sorry. I've now added `(global-set-key (kbd "M-/") 'hippie-expand)` to my `.emacs`, and added the `setq` given [here](http://trey-jackson.blogspot.co.uk/2007/12/emacs-tip-5-hippie-expand.html), and restarted Emacs. However, now when I hit `M-/` while in the middle of typing a substitution command, Emacs outputs "No expansion found", even if the string I am typing is an initial substring of a string further on in the file. Perhaps I'm missing something...

Comment: It may be some quirk with Evil's command mode, because it works for me when using the minibuffer during `eval-expression` (`M-:`)

Comment: @nanny that would be because `hippie-expand` is treating the `s/` as part of the symbol to complete.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `q/` or `q:`, then you'll be able to complete using cross buffer completion with auto-complete or company, if you have them configured.

To configure company for that, you need to add the backends `company-dabbrev-code` and/or `company-dabbrev` to `company-backends`. Then invoking company-complete should bring the completion.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I've upvoted, but haven't yet tried `auto-complete` or `company`, so can't yet confirm that this works for me. Will try to remember to mark it as "correct" once I have, assuming [Evil bug #166](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issues/166/some-key-bindings-are-missing-in-command#comment-20876335) still stands.